# Combine keys with .lower() and sum up values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary with keys that can be either upper or lower case. All my values are int. I want to do .lower() on all my keys and sum up the values for the keys that will map to the same lower case key.

Example input:

```
{'banana':3, 'Banana': 2, 'apple': 4, 'PeAr':7}
```

Output:

```
{'banana':5, 'apple': 4, 'pear':7}
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but just a suggestion: Solve this problem **before** storing keys with the same name, if you can help it. I know the capitalization is changing, so they're not "the same," but this just seems like a really poor practice in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I would if I could

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you will want to avoid this problem before it even exists. When creating the original dictionary, simply call `.lower()` on the key before storing it in the dictionary.

Anyway, you can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'banana':3, 'Banana': 2, 'apple': 4, 'PeAr':7}

out = defaultdict(int)

for k, v in d.items():
    out[k.lower()] += v

print(out)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'banana': 5, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 7})
```

A bit longer solution without `defaultdict`:

```
d = {'banana': 3, 'Banana': 2, 'apple': 4, 'PeAr': 7}

out = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    k = k.lower()
    try:
        out[k] += v
    except KeyError:
        out[k] = v

print(out)
# {'banana': 5, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 7}
```

Or even with `.setdefault` although personally I'm not a fan (partially because you have to mention the key twice, and the default value may potentially change between iterations if it is not hard-coded).

```
d = {'banana': 3, 'Banana': 2, 'apple': 4, 'PeAr': 7}

out = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    k = k.lower()
    out[k] = out.setdefault(k, 0) + v

print(out)
# {'banana': 5, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [lists comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

This could leads you to something like:

```
result = {k.lower(): sum([mydict[x] for x in mydict if x.lower() == k.lower()]) for k, v in mydict.items()}
```